# Relative directory does not point correctly in script src

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

**Problem Summary:**

I have a simple html boilerplate that I'm trying to link a javascript file to, something I've done a million times. However, when I write my script tag Visual Studio is giving me the following warning:

> Warning   TS6053  (JS) File
>   '//PROAPPSRV/inetpub/wwwroot/WorkOrder-New/ConfigApp/Assets/templates/packages/mustache.js.0.7.2/content/Scripts/mustache.js'
>   not
>   found.

Now I know this seems cut and dry, the file I'm pointing to is not at that location. Which is true, however, the location in the warning is not the location I'm pointing to with my script tag.

**Problem Details:**

Here is my script tag:

`<script src="/packages/mustache.js.0.7.2/content/Scripts/mustache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

As you can see I'm pointing to the root directory, and then into the packages/etc to find the .js file.

Folder Structure:

WorkOrder-New(**root**) > ConfigApp > Assets > templates > quote_template.html

WorkOrder-New(**root**) > packages > mustache.js.0.7.2 > content > Scripts > mustache.js

And as you can see, the directory it's trying to hit is:

//PROAPPSRV/inetpub/wwwroot/WorkOrder-New/ConfigApp/Assets/templates/packages/mustache.js.0.7.2/content/Scripts/mustache.js

So it's essentially treating my src as if I had left the '/' off the front and were looking for a subfolder in my starting directory.

**What I've Tried:**

- I tried to google this error as many ways as I could think to phrase it, but didn't find anything that seemed to be a similar issue.
- I verified the case of the folder and files to make sure I wasn't messing it up with improper case. I also tried linking it through Visual Studio's UI, with the same result.
- I attempted to use a different a non relative path by changing my script tag to:

`<script src="../../../packages/mustache.js.0.7.2/content/Scripts/mustache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Which instead gives me this path in the error:

//PROAPPSRV/inetpub/wwwroot/WorkOrder-New/ConfigApp/Assets/templates/PROAPPSRV/inetpub/wwwroot/WorkOrder-New/packages/mustache.js.0.7.2/content/Scripts/mustache.js

Which just looks like it's looking for the complete correct directory within the folder the html file is in.

**Summary:**

I'm sure there's some config setting or something that is at the root of this problem, but I'm not sure what it would be and I inherited this admittedly messy project so I'm hoping someone can point out where I'm going wrong here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is it an asp.net core application?

Comment: then you need to put the js file inside the wwwroot folder

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier No, asp.net 4.5.2. Putting it in wwwroot would put it at a higher level than my project. I've never had to do that with any other file references.